# RANUNI Function in SAS

Tags: sas, call

I want a solution to the problem where I have to use the RANUNI in a DO loop and call, and generate 10 samples, each of size 15, the value of the random variable is a number between 10 and 20.
Since I have to use Call Routine, I am not able to get variables between 10 and 20. After having the following code, I am generating values between 0 to 1.

So far I have done this-

````
DATA seven;
DO i=1 TO 15;
 CALL RANUNI(2020, x1);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, x2);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, X5);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, X6);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, X7);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, X8);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, x3);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, x4);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, x9);
 CALL RANUNI(2020, x10);
 OUTPUT;
END;
PROC PRINT DATA=SEVEN NOOBS ;
RUN;
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use the [`CALL STREAMINIT`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0gw58qo85qp56n1kbpiz50ww8lv.htm) routine with the [RAND()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0fpeei0opypg8n1b06qe4r040lv.htm) function

```
data want;
call streaminit(2120);

do sample=1 to 10;
    do obs=1 to 15;
        rand=rand('uniform', 10, 20);
        output;
    end;
end;

drop obs;
run;
```

```
sample    rand
  1    14.767593681
  1    13.535240577
  1    12.954676473
  1    10.660713173
  1    13.894441081
  1    10.843995532
 ...       ...
 10   13.716131395
 10   13.261181149
 10   17.789552165
```

Comment: and you can use `rand('integer',10,20)` if you want integers